# How to set event-listener for spinner default item?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner which loads four different value one, two, three, four.
**'one'** is default selected value in spinner.
in spinner popup, select one then 'onItemSelected()' not fire...

but select any other then it is fire...
so how to implement?
please help me....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is builtin issue in android. instead of putting first value in it. Insert text like "---Select Value---" at first place and add all values after this text. So by default u will see this text. And then you can easily select any which you want.

Like:

```
String[] items = new String[] {"---Select Any---","One", "Two", "Three"};
```

Comment: i use this code,but when second time selection problem as it is..

Comment: What means second times?

Comment: And one more thing when you select any number one time than you will not reselect it again because it has been already selected. You can first select another and then reselect it. I am using this type of code and it is working nicely

Comment: when i select two then popup close and selected value is two..that time i open popup and select same value (two) that time not event fire

Comment: i know,this code work properly....but client can not understand this situation...thanks bro for help....